# Memory not performing as expected

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard, speed

This is probably a noob question but I really don't know why this is happening

I bought the below parts recently

ASRock 970 Pro3 R2.0 Motherboard

HyperX Savage 8GB (1 x 8GB) Memory Module 2133MHz DDR3 CL11 DIMM

I ran a Futuremark test and it said the memory clock was 800 Mhz

What could be affecting the performance so drastically? There is only one memory module in the board.

Comment: A tad late, but please notice that the modules '2133MHz' means that it runs at 1066 real MHz. (DDR signaling makes it twice as efficient so marketing lies and doubles the spedd number. A kind a to 100kmph car which goes 50kmph with two passengers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that its only one chip, so you are running at [single channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture), meaning your highest possible frequency is about 1066Mhz.

Additionally, at present, in order to get speeds greater than 1600, you need to enable an overclocked [XMP profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#XMP) in the BIOS for most motherboards. Since you are in Single-Channel mode, the frequency for 1600Mhz ram would be halved to 800Mhz.

See section 3.3 of [your usermanaual](ftp://66.226.78.21/manual/970%20Pro3%20R2.0.pdf) starting on page 44, for instructions on how to set the RAM to use its full 1066Mhz. The settings you want to configure are under the DRAM Timing Configuration section. I suggest you look at the Load Profile Setting feature, and select an XMP profile that is right for your hardware.

Comment: Of course you can avoid all of this by using multiple memory modules so it can run in the proper channel mode.

Comment: Agreed, but if you are using 2133Mhz ram, even in dual channel you still have to enable an XMP timing profile (or have a mobo newe nough to implement the JEDEC 2133 profile, which is still rare), to get more than 800Mhz per channel.

Comment: This motherboard should support that profile.  It has 2100 Mhz memory on the supported memory list.  This appears like the major problem `The mainboard supports DDR3-2000 MHz DIMMs only when you install a 6-core cpu to the mainboard.` in other configuration will result in as you point out pretty severe overclocking.

Comment: I have a 6 core cpu so once the other memory module arrives I'll leave a comment whether or not it worked

Comment: Futuremark still says the memory modules are running @800 Mhz. I checked in the BIOS and dual channel mode is enabled